# Replace primary key, which is also used as a foreign key, with a different value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, foreign-keys, primary-key

My Current database schema looks as below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS w4a_authentication_data (
    login_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (login_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS w4a_user (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    login_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    first_name VARCHAR(100),
    last_name VARCHAR(100),
    division INTEGER NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    last_active DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (login_id) REFERENCES w4a_authentication_data (login_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (division) REFERENCES w4a_division (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS w4a_contact_number(
    contact_number VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    is_confirmed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    PRIMARY KEY (contact_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES w4a_user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE 
);
```

My data base currently have data in all these tables. Now I need to replace values used for login ID with the contact number of the particular user selected from the w4a_contact_number table. How can I do this?

Comment: Specify ON UPDATE CASCADE for according reference then update parent value - slave value will be updated automatically. If no duplicate violation occures, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, you need to change the definition of the foreign key that links `w4a_user` to `w4a_authentication_data` to add the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` option:

```
FOREIGN KEY (login_id) 
    REFERENCES w4a_authentication_data (login_id) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Then, you can use the `update ... join` syntax:

```
update w4a_authentication_data ad 
inner join w4a_user u on u.login_id = ad.login_id
inner join w4a_contact_number cn on cn.user_id = u.id
set ad.login_id = cn.contact_number
```

The database tracks down the modified values and updates the dependent columns accordingly.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=abeff7a6bf55e55bb438e5f8b73c0fbc)**

Comment: You probably mean `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in the first sentence.